# An Extreme Point of a closed ball of $\ell^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that all "closed unit ball" of
$$
c_0 = \{ \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^\infty : \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0\}
$$
do not have any extreme point.

(Extreme Point) Let $X$ be a vector space and $A \subset X$ be convex. We say $x\in A$ is "Extreme Point" if for $x = (1-t)y + tz,\; y,z,\in A, \;t\in(0,1)$ then $y = z = x$.

What I tried is as follows:

Let $B$ be a closed unit ball of $c_0$, that is, $$B = \{\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^\infty : \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = 0 \text{ and } \|x\|_{\ell^\infty}\le 1\}.$$
If there is a extreme point $b = \{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\in B$, then we have for
$$
b = (1-t)y + tz, \quad y,z\in B,\quad t\in (0,1)
$$
implies
$$
y = z = b.
$$
But I cannot do anymore here. Would you please help me?

Comment: @LeBtz But I could not understand the answer there sorry

Comment: Why did you accept the answer then instead of writing a comment there telling what specifically you didn't understand?

Comment: Argue directly. For example $x=(1/2,1/4,1/8,\ldots)$ is not extreme since $x={1\over 2}(1/2\color{green}{+1/10},1/4,1/8,\ldots)+{1\over2}(1/2\color{green}{-1/10},1/4,1/8,\ldots)$.

Comment: @JohnS You should [never ask the same question twice](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6714/can-i-ask-the-same-question-twice). If your question was put on hold, you should edit it instead. (I have added your attempt to the older question. Let's wait and see whether that will be sufficient to get it reopened.)

Comment: BTW if you were not getting sufficient answer on main, you could also have asked in chat. [The main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/36/mathematics) and the [room for functional analysis](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/30484/functional-analysis-study-group) seem like reasonable candidates for this particular question. More general advice what to do if your question did not receive enough attention: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question)